# How to convert this react-style fetch-api to next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, sanity

I've just realised the way I've been fetching data from my backend (Sanity) is better suited for react app than next, so I'm trying to convert what I have at the moment. For transparency, I'm trying to call the first image within an array of images (as well as the set_name, hence why I have tried to query both the overall set with its fields, and the array within the set),

This is what I originally had to extract an image from each set:

```
const [ galleryData, setGalleryData ] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  client.fetch(
    `*[_type == 'set']{
      set_name,
      'setSelect' : set_images[0].asset->{_id,url}}`
  ).then((data) => setGalleryData(data))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
})
```

This is what I have tried but I'm getting a server error:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const query = '*[_type == "set"]';
  const set = await client.fetch(query)

  const imagesQuery = '*[_type == "set"]{set_images.asset->{_id,url}}';
  const setImages = await client.fetch(imagesQuery)

  return {
    props: {set, setImages}
  }
```

Comment: try to change ' by ` in imagesQuery

Comment: sorry I'm completely new to this, what does that mean?

Comment: on line 4 change ' with ` like u have in reactjs fetch

Comment: Oh I see, that didn't work either, same error: ClientError: Attribute or a string key expected

Comment: _"I'm getting a server error"_ - What server error are you getting?

Comment: ClientError: Attribute or a string key expected is what I got

Answer (score 0):

That error is coming from GROQ because part of your projection (`set_images.asset->{_id,url}`) needs a key value. Try something like:

```
const imagesQuery = '*[_type == "set"]{'set_images': set_images.asset->{_id,url}}';
```